# average the same ones and then find the max on the list

Tags: excel, vba, function, max, average

So I have a table like this :

Company / Score

Apple  / 5

Banana / 4

Kiwi   / 3

Apple  / 4

Banana / 2

I need to find the best performing company from this. Basically find average of the companies with more than one score and then search entire list to find which one has the max score. so here the value to return will be Apple. Is this even possible in function level without writing average values in a column to search for the max? if not what is the way to do it in VBA?

Comment: No need for VBA here. Formulas: =COUNTIF will show you how many times a company is on the list. =AVERAGEIF will give you the average for the company, =MAX, well I shouldn't have to explain that one.

Comment: You can use Power Query, and find the average and then sort desc on the average and then select the first 1 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table as you give it is in `A1:B6` (with headers in row 1):

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+AVERAGEIF(A2:A6,A2:A6,B2:B6))),A2:A6)`

If more than one company share the highest average score than that occurring first within the list will be returned.

Regards

Comment: How does this work when my list starts from row number 4 not one with the headers on row 3?

Comment: Just amend the rows being referenced accordingly within the formula I posted.